# How to trigger a Future method when a new document in Firestore is created. Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Future which call a Ringtone with this [dependency](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ringtone_player)

```
Future<void> getRing()async {
FlutterRingTonePlayer.playAlarm();
}
```

I want to trigger the method `getRing` when a new document is created into my collection and add a new item in the list.
How I can achieve that without creating a firebase function?

Answer (score 2):

You can read data from Firestore in realtime using [streams](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes) and track changes to collection with QuerySnapshot's [docChanges](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) property.

Just subscribe to collection using .snapshots(), inspect document changes in received QuerySnapshot and trigger your Future if there is a new doc.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for `stream` see the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) for more info

```
CollectionReference reference = Firestore.instance.collection('YOUR_COLLECTION');
reference.snapshots().listen((querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.documentChanges.forEach((change) {
    // Do something with change
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok but where to call getRing() method?

Comment: Inside `// Do something with change`

Comment: @EmanuelDeveloper in this case you can create a bool 'isNewDocumentAdded' before forEach function and check if 'change.type == DocumentChangeType.added' then set your isNewDocumentAdded to true and trigger your getRing() after forEach bloc if your isNewDocumentAdded == true.